# X509Certificate validation with SerialNumber or Public Key

Tags: public-key-encryption, x509certificate2

Can anyone offer some advice on validating a X509Certificate. I am already checking to see if the cert is signed by a trusted root, however I also want to check that the certificate is issued to a known party.

What is the best property to use for this? I'm thinking along the lines of SerialNumber or Public Key but don't fully understand the implications of either. I guess public key lives beyond any reissued certificates, whereas SerialNumber is constrained to a particular certificate issued on a particular date?

Can anyone offer some informed advice?

*Edit:* It looks like the certificate thumbprint might be the typical way to achieve this.

Comment: You can find some informations about certificate validation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx. After the X509Chain.ChainPolicy property is configured to meet your requirements, the X509Chain.Build method can be used to check if the certificate is valid. In case is not valid the X509Chain.ChainStatus property will provide you detailed error information.

Comment: Thanks this doesn't help with the question though. I know how to validate the certificate, I'm looking for a way to identity who it's issued to, without resorting to string matching the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is a Thumbprint property which uniquely identifies the exact certificate details.

However in the end I reverted to string matching the Company Name in the Subject, as it's the only way I could know for sure that I could validate renewed or re-issued certificates.